# Unable to install AutoItLibrary in windows

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

```
>pip install AutoItLibrary
```

Collecting AutoItLibrary
Using cached AutoItLibrary-1.1.post1.zip (482 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [7 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\samrins\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zeihf1a8\autoitlibrary_e6935c1fdc7a414a8f3694d5f9101d89\setup.py", line 57
print "Don't think we need to unregister the old one..."
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Comment: how about if you try to install "robotframework-autoitlibrary" ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing the correct library. AutoItLibrary is an old one, not updated since 2010 following this page https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/

The one you should used is the library [robotframework-autoitlibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary) as referenced on https://robotframework.org/#resources